# How can I calculate numbers in a list?

Tags: python

For example, we have these lists:

```py
l1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
l2 = [11, 11, 2]
l3 = [5, 6]
l4 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Here, `l2` and `l3` have 2 numbers (`11` and `2` for `l2`, and `5` and `6` for `l3`)
`l1` has 4 numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`)
`l4` has 3 numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`)

How can I calculate that? (assuming the list is unknown)

Thank you!

Comment: You can convert the lists in sets and then use `len()` to see how many unique numbers are in them. Something like `len(set(l1))`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the lists to sets and use `len()` to see how many unique numbers are in each of them. Something like this:

```py
>>> l1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
>>> l2 = [11, 11, 2]
>>> l3 = [5, 6]
>>> l4 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>>> len(set(l1))
4
>>> len(set(l2))
2
>>> len(set(l3))
2
>>> len(set(l4))
3
>>>
```

And to see the unique elements, the following will show you them:

```py
>>> set(l1)
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(len(list(dict.fromkeys(l2)))
```

explanation:
len - method that return length of list
list - converts dict to list
dict.fromkeys - create dictionary from given list

(values that repeat will be appended to dictionary just once because its dictionary :) it couldnt have two definitions of one variable )

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using list of list:

```
def numbersList(l1):
    return len(set(l1))

nList = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],[11, 11, 2], [5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]]
for l in nList:
    print(numbersList(l))
    
# if you want to add more list to list
print("After Append")
nList.append([3,3,3,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,10])
for l in nList:
    print(numbersList(l))
```